# Update value in range and ListBox with the value in a TextBox on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, listbox, userform

I was hoping someone could help me with this. I am designing a user form that will populate a list box with values from a range in a worksheet. The goal is to populate a row of text boxes with the list box row (which I have working correctly) and then use the textboxes to change the values in the range and list box. This final step is where I am having trouble. Does anyone know a way of accomplishing this? Below is the code I used to populate the textboxes. Is there some way to invert this to write the text box values to the range / list box? Also attached is an image of the user form as it is now. Thanks!

```
Private Sub ProgList_Click()
StepTxt.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput _
.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:F24"), 1, False)
DateCompTxt.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput _
.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:F24"), 2, False)
CompByTxt.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput _
.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:F24"), 3, False)
CheckByTxt.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput _
.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:F24"), 4, False)
CommTxt.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput _
.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:F24"), 5, False)
Me.DateCompTxt.Text = Format(Me.DateCompTxt.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Listbox1.ListIndex will give the index on a single select listbox. Starts with 0 - zero. In your screenshot that would be 1. Then range.offset(row off, col off) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Index of the row to be edited with commandbutton click could be found with `Match` function. So, once the text in the textboxes is edited, clicking on commandbutton will change the text in the given range as per textbox and  also update the listbox with rowsource property. Try this ...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rw As Long

rw = Application.Match(Me.ProgList, Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24"), 0)
Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24").Cells(rw, 1) = StepTxt.Value
Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24").Cells(rw, 2) = DateCompTxt.Value
Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24").Cells(rw, 3) = CompByTxt.Value
Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24").Cells(rw, 4) = CheckByTxt.Value
Sheets(EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value).Range("B15:B24").Cells(rw, 5) = CommTxt.Value
ProgList.RowSource = EditProjNumInput.ProjNumTxt.Value & "!B15:F24"

End Sub
```